# Sending django FileField content as an email attachment with smtplib in python?

Tags: python, django, email, smtplib, filefield

I want to send emails with various attachments. These attachments are stored as FileField in a django model. I manage to create the mail and to send an attachment, but the attachment is empty, whereas I would like it to contain the FileField content. Thanks for your help!

```
def sendEmailHtml(fromaddr, toaddrs, body, subject, attachmentFiles=[]):
    """ Sends HTML email using hardcoded server parameters

    attachmentFiles is a list of FileFields
    """
    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddrs
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    # Create the body of the message
    html = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        """+body+"""
      </body>
    </html>
    """
    # Record the MIME types of the parts 
    part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    # Attach parts into message container.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
    # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    msg.attach(part1)
    # add attachments
    for file in attachmentFiles:       
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(unicode(file.read(), 'utf-8'))
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', 
               filename=file.name)
        msg.attach(part)        

    # Send the message via local SMTP server.
    username = 'example@gmail.com'
    password = 'examplepwd'
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

I guess that the following lines are somehow wrong, so I have tried many different version, without success for the moment. Your help will be appreciated.

```
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(unicode(file.read(), 'utf-8'))
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
```

EDIT: I do not understand why file.read() returned empty content... If anyone can explain, that'll be great. Anyway, here is a corrected function, which works:

```
def sendEmailHtml(fromaddr, toaddrs, body, subject, attachmentFiles=[]):
    """ Sends HTML email using hardcoded server parameters

    attachmentFiles is a list of FileFields
    """
    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative for alternative
    # formats of the same content. It's related otherwise (e.g., attachments).
    msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddrs
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
    # Note: email readers do not support CSS... We have to put everything in line
    html = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        """+body+"""
      </body>
    </html>
    """
    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    # Attach parts into message container.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
    # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    msg.attach(part1)
    # add attachments
    # for debugging
    debug = False
    if debug:
        # force the presence of a single attachment
        if (len(attachmentFiles)!=1):            
            raise NameError("The number of attachments must be exactly 1, not more, not less.")
        else:
            # print the value of every possible way to obtain the content
            content = "[1] "+unicode(attachmentFiles[0].read(), 'utf-8')
            content += "[2] "+attachmentFiles[0].read()
            content += "[3] "+str(attachmentFiles[0])
            content += "[4] "+open(str(attachmentFiles[0]),'r').read()            
            if (len(content)==0):
                raise NameError("The file to be attached is empty !")
            else:
                # print the content
                raise NameError("Everything ok: content="+content)
                pass
    # end of debugging code
    for file in attachmentFiles:
        format, enc = mimetypes.guess_type(file.name)
        main, sub = format.split('/')
        part = MIMEBase(main, sub)       
        #part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(open(str(file),'r').read())
        #Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        Encoders.encode_quopri(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', 
               filename=file.name)
        msg.attach(part)        

    # Send the message via local SMTP server.
    username = 'example@gmail.com'
    password = 'thepassword'
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

NB: I forgot the close directive after the open.

Comment: `multipart/alternative` is used when you have multiple parts that represent the same content (e.g. plain text and HTML, with the mail reader displaying the version it supports).  If you use `multipart/related` instead, does that help?

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I have corrected to multipart/related, however, my attachment is still an empty file

Comment: I have debugged quite a lot.

unicode(attachmentFiles[0].read(), 'utf-8')   is empty

attachmentFiles[0].read() is empty too

str(attachmentFiles[0]) contains the filename.

So, I'll try to open the file without directly reading the FileField but rather with a usual open command on the filename.